# Create a new field with a boolean value based on whether given document's value is in an array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Given I have array of ids, e.g.:

```
db.calendars.aggregate([
   { '$match' : { _id: { '$in' : filtered_ids } }  },
   { '$group' : { _id: null, ids: { '$push' : '$_id' }  }  },
   { '$project' : {_id: 0, ids: 1} }
])
{ "ids" : [ ObjectId("5d9ce5d73ed1492058a3a2df"), ObjectId("5d9ce88e3ed14921b6e1a9f1"), ObjectId("5d9ce88e3ed14921b6e1a9f3") ] }
```

I want to create a new field in the below aggregation pipeline which evaluates to `1` or `-1` if the given document id exists or not in the above array of ids. In effect, I will be able to sort the documents by a boolean value. It seems at first, the `'$cmp'` operator is suitable.

```
db.calendars.aggregate([
  { '$addFields' : { 'shared' : { '$cmp' : ['$_id', [ ObjectId("5d9ce5d73ed1492058a3a2df"), ObjectId("5d9ce88e3ed14921b6e1a9f1"), ObjectId("5d9ce88e3ed14921b6e1a9f3") ] ] } },
  { '$sort' : { shared: -1 }  }
])
```

But the '$cmp' operator only compared the two values. It does not do what '$in' does to compare whether one value is in an array of values. My question is how can I incorporate that '$in' requirement when comparing the values.

An expected result would look like this:

```
{ '_id' : Object('...'), name: 'New event', shared: -1 },
{ '_id' : Object('...'), name: 'Another event', shared: -1 },
{ '_id' : Object('...'), name: 'Cool event', shared: 1 },
{ '_id' : Object('...'), name: 'Wow, an event', shared: 1 },
```

You see how the documents are sorted by that new field?

Comment: Could you show sample documents and expected result ?

Comment: @mickl I added an expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/index.html) returns a boolean value so you can use [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/index.html) to set `1` or `-1`:

```
db.calendars.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            shared: {
                $cond: [ { $in: [ "$_id", [ ObjectId("5d9ce5d73ed1492058a3a2df"), ObjectId("5d9ce88e3ed14921b6e1a9f1"), ObjectId("5d9ce88e3ed14921b6e1a9f3") ] ] }, 1, -1 ]
            }
        }
    },
    { '$sort' : { shared: -1 }  }
])
```

or run `$sort` on boolean if you want to simplify:

```
db.calendars.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            shared: {
                $in: [ "$_id", [ ObjectId("5d9ce5d73ed1492058a3a2df"), ObjectId("5d9ce88e3ed14921b6e1a9f1"), ObjectId("5d9ce88e3ed14921b6e1a9f3") ] ] 
            }
        }
    },
    { '$sort' : { shared: -1 }  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer. I must be careful to distinguish [`$in` **aggregation** operator you linked](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) vs the [`$in` **query** operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)